# Como puedo preguntar a un elemento cual es su clase?

Tags: javascript, python, clase

Miren, tengo este codigo en una pagina web:

```
<div _ngcontent-serverapp-c175="" class="a_9 logo-insurance"></div>
<div _ngcontent-serverapp-c175="" class="a_11 logo-insurance"></div>
<div _ngcontent-serverapp-c175="" class="a_5 logo-insurance"></div>
```

Y yo lo que quiero hacer es preguntarle a cada uno independientemente, y que me responda, mi clase es: a_9 logo-insurance, para guardar eso en una variable, porque quiero hacer cosas distintas dependiendo de que clase sea. O me pregunto si tambien se podria decirle if tu clase es:  a_9 logo-insurance, entonces yo ya la guardo en una varible, pero no se. Necesito que sea JavaScript o Python.

Enserio gracias!!

Comment: con javascript puedes hacerlo accediendo a su atributo con `'id_del elemento'.getAttribute("class")`

Answer (score 1):

Para obtener las clases de varios elementos primero debes obtenerlos mediante una selección, luego recorrer los elementos encontrados y sacar su atributo class. Para que esto sea más manejable puedes hacer un split con el fin de tener las clases separadas en un `array` en vez de `string`.

```js
let selected_elements = document.querySelectorAll('div')

selected_elements.forEach((element, index) => {
  let classes = element.getAttribute("class").split(" ") 
  // Acá classes tiene todas las clases del elemento como array
  console.log("clases del elemento", index + 1, classes)
  
  // acá puedes validar si el elemento tiene o no una clase
  if(classes.includes('a_5')){
    console.log(`El elemento ${index + 1} tiene la clase a_5`)
  }
  
})
```

```html
<div _ngcontent-serverapp-c175="" class="a_9 logo-insurance"></div>
<div _ngcontent-serverapp-c175="" class="a_11 logo-insurance"></div>
<div _ngcontent-serverapp-c175="" class="a_5 logo-insurance"></div>
```

Si quieres las clases de un elemento en particular reemplaza `.querySelectorAll()` por `.querySelector()` y elimina los ciclos, ya que la ultima función solo entregará un elemento, por lo tanto no es iterable.
Ahora que tienes tu selección puedes continuar con `.getAttribute("class").split(" ")`.

Answer (score 0):

`.classList` con destructuring es una posible forma de tener en un array las clases de un elemento:

```js
const divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");// <-- No es necesario que seleccionemes asi

[...divs].forEach(d =>

  [...d.classList].includes("a_9") && console.log("Hacemos algo")

);
```

```html
<div _ngcontent-serverapp-c175="" class="a_9 logo-insurance"></div>
<div _ngcontent-serverapp-c175="" class="a_11 logo-insurance"></div>
<div _ngcontent-serverapp-c175="" class="a_5 logo-insurance"></div>
```